# error in creating EntityManager object

Tags: weblogic, openjpa

I am trying to create a EntityManager object for persistence and I am unable to create EntityManager object. Please find the sample code below:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Draco-PU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

I have defined the persistence unit name in persistence.xml file too.

```
<persistence-unit name="Draco-PU" >
```

The persistence xml is as defined below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns
/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="Draco-PU" >
<provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
<jta-data-source>DracoDataSource</jta-data-source>
<non-jta-data-source>DracoUnmanagedDataSource</non-jta-data-source>
<class>dk.tdc.soa.smo.draco.db.model.DslServiceEntity</class>
<class>dk.tdc.soa.smo.draco.db.model.DslServiceCatalogEntity</class>
<class>dk.tdc.soa.smo.draco.db.model.History</class>
<class>dk.tdc.soa.smo.draco.db.model.ConfigEntity</class>
<properties>
  <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARNING, Runtime=WARNING, Tool=WARNING, SQL=WARNING" />
  <!-- <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.OracleDictionary" />  -->     
  <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)" />
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The error faced is :

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager
named Draco-PU: Provider named kodo.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl threw 
expected exception at create EntityManagerFactory:
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException<openjpa-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT-
r422266:891341 fatal general error>  
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There was an error when invoking
the static newInstance method on the named factory class 
"kodo.jdbc.kernel.KodoJDBCBrokerFactory".
```

Please help!

Comment: Please post the error you get, otherwise we won't be able to help!

Comment: @ppeterka error is posted. Please check

Comment: I already have the persistence provider defined in the persistence xml.But the error still exists

Comment: I think it would help if you includd the whole `persistence.xml` file

Comment: @ppeterka I have included the whole persistence.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare a "provider" element within your "persistence-unit" element in persistence.xml?  It should look something like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="Draco-PU">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Yes! I already have that defined in the persistence xml.But the error still exists

Answer (score 0):

Create the next structure inside your WEB-INF folder: classes/META-INF, put your persistence.xml file in and restart the server.

Weblogic looks for the file in the build directory.